# Tools and algorithms for angles-only orbit estimation

Tags: amateur-observing, celestial-mechanics, satellite, astrometry

I've seen discussion threads where amateur astronomers estimate a satellite's [orbital parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_elements) from angles-only telescope observation.  Are there any community tools or algorithms to help with this math? It's not a trivial problem to solve.

Comment: My thinking is that you'd use curve fitting techniques to match the observations to a best fit ellipse. You should also be able to estimate the period directly, which will give you the distance which should help.

Comment: Do you mean algorithms to estimate the position using its right ascension and declination? There are several methods available for that.

Comment: I'd like to estimate all the orbital parameters -- apogee, perigee, inclination, etc. I know it's done, but I was hoping for some libraries / tools to help do the job so I'm not coding up journal articles.

Comment: It looks like https://www.narom.no/undervisningsressurser/sarepta/rocket-theory/satellite-orbits/introduction-of-the-six-basic-parameters-describing-satellite-orbits/ describes what you are after.